# Draw a circle within svg countdown

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have made an example countdown using svg but i need a clock face which would be just a dark circle which is being filled with the colour of the countdown which i made.

Here is the code i got:

```js
var time = 1800;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1

/* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('h3').text(secondsToTime(1800-i).m.toString()+" min " +secondsToTime(1800-i).s.toString()+" sek");
  if (i == time) {   
      clearInterval(interval);
   return;
    }
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
    i++;
}, 1000);


function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
   
    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
 
    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
   
    var obj = {
        "m": minutes,
        "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
}
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h3 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
    <h3>0</h3>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="15" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

This is the result i am looking for (dark clock face) and countdown filling it out:
[image: dark clock face]

One of my tries to accomplish what i want was adding a new css class named "circle" but it does not seem to show up when i add it to `<circle id="circle" class="circle circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="15" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>`.

```js
var time = 1800;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1

/* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('h3').text(secondsToTime(1800-i).m.toString()+" min " +secondsToTime(1800-i).s.toString()+" sek");
  if (i == time) {   
      clearInterval(interval);
   return;
    }
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
    i++;
}, 1000);


function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
   
    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
 
    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
   
    var obj = {
        "m": minutes,
        "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
}
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h3 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.circle {
    border: 15px solid #03002e;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius:50%;
    width: 125px;
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
    <h3>30 min 00 sek</h3>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="15" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: How long does it take to fill 100%? 30 minutes?

Comment: @jack It does, but for testing you can change value of var time = 1800 to something else like 1 and it will be instantly filled.

Comment: You can use for the circle property `fill: red;`. If you don't like ho it looks, then create another circle behind the animated strip.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Fill would just fill whole circle and hide text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another circle to your svg area before the current circle and make sure it doesn't have the same class the one you are animating. `<circle id="circle" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="15" stroke="#1F2837" fill="none"/>`

You can see a [demo on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hifewuyutu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Great answer, even colours fit! :D